# How to reorder a list based on the known order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, ranking, rank

In python3, if I have a list `[a,b,c,d,e]`, and its ranking order `[1,4,2,2,0]` with element `c` and `d` sharing the same order. How can I get a new list `[e,a,c,d,b]`?

Comment: Note, `sorted(zip(ranklist, mylist))` gives you something like `[(0, 'e'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (4, 'b')]`

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `map = dict(zip(mylist, ranklist))` then `sorted(mylist, key=map.get)`

Comment: The linked to accepted answer linked to involves a sorting algorithm which I assume to be a n log(n) operation. It's possible to do an in-place reordering in O(n) time. Link to example for [reorder according to rank](http://www.cdn.geeksforgeeks.org/reorder-a-array-according-to-given-indexes) (note the title of this example doesn't mention rank, but it is a reorder by rank.)

Comment: I'm wondering how common reorder according to rank is. If you generate an array of indices 0 to n-1, then sort the indices according to the array, you get something like [4,0,2,3,1] (order is list[4], list[0], list[2], list[3], list[1]) instead of the rank [1,4,2,3,0]. You can produce the rank from indices sorted according to an array: rank[index[i]] = i, or vice versa: index[rank[i]] = i.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a a detailed algorithm with similarities to the "Bubble Sort":

```
original = [a,b,c,d,e]
order = [1,4,2,2,0]

# Initialize list
new = [None for x in range(len(original))]

for i, item in enumerate(original):
    idx = order[i]
    if new[idx] is None:
        new[idx] = item
    else:
        while True:
            if new[idx] < item:
                idx += 1
                if new[idx] is None:
                    new[idx] = item
                    break
            else:
                temp = new[idx]
                new[idx] = item
                while True:
                    idx += 1
                    if new[idx] is None:
                        new[idx] = temp
                        break
                    else:
                        temp2 = new[idx]
                        new[idx] = temp
                        temp = temp2
```